# Import Cost Understanding in Web Apps

Tags: javascript, performance, visual-studio-code, import, web-applications

I am a newbie and using React for app development. I just want to understand the importing cost.

For e.g. if I am using axios, what costing effects it will have for client side?

One cost is the download size of the package which is 346KB.

Questions:

1. And if I am importing axios in 3 files and using it so will the cost be added for all three files or will it be counted just once no matter how many times you import it?
2. Is 346KB a bigger size which can affect performance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1.It adds only once. And if you have setup code-splitting it will load only when page with this import opens. 2. It will take gzipped minified file, which has 5.2k only

Comment: @demkovych thanks :)